# Why would I use FEB (Flash Exposure Bracketing)?

Tags: flash, exposure, bracketing

In what situation would using FEB (Flash Exposure Bracketing) be a good idea?  Exposure bracketing can be blended together with HDR, but why would I use FEB?

Comment: This is pretty well covered on the wikipedia topic... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracketing#Flash_bracketing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have lost track of the original reason for AEB: To be sure you nailed the exposure. In this case you use small increments (up to 1 EV at most) while for HDR you would use larger steps (at least 3 stops but 5 is good with modern cameras).

For FEB, it is the same: **To be sure you nailed the flash exposure.**

Comment: Specifically, you might use FEB to be sure you nailed the balance of flash and ambient light. This can be hard to judge without a lot of experience, and testing is often the easiest way. If you can't test, an automatic sequence might do.